# Why SpringBootTest Vm Options Not Working?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm

It seems there are many similar questions. But my problem is not solved, so I ask.

I am using SpringBoot and Intellij combination.

And the VM Option called "-Djasypt.encryptor.password" is set in Intellij.

This recognizes the option and operates without any problems in the SpringBoot environment.

That is, no problems so far.

However, it is not recognized at all in the @SpringBootTest environment for testing.

Of course, I entered it separately in Test VmOption.

I added the same Vm Option to ProjectNameApplicationTests, which is automatically generated in Run/Debug Configurations, but my tests do not work because the above password is not in the settings.

That is, the Vm Option is being ignored.

In a normal project environment there is no problem. But only in test environment why Vm Option doesn't recognize it?

[Error]

```
Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'jasypt.encryptor.password' in value
```

[image]

Comment: Does that command fork a VM to run your app? If so, the forked vm won't be getting the system property. With maven you can use -Dspring-boot.run.fork=false so that the spring-boot-maven-plugin will run the application in the same VM.

Comment: Alternatively (again in maven), if you do want to fork, use -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Djasype.encryptor.password=hunter2"

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm using gradle not maven. And I'm sorry I don't understand the word vm branching.

Comment: Gradle runs in a JVM. It can either run your spring boot app in the same JVM, or start ("fork") another JVM. I imagine that there are similar command line options for gradle to the maven ones I mentioned -- check the documentation.